# Dynamically Pass stubs to a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, sinon

I have a component with a large number of props, but I only need to test a handful are being called in my enzyme tests.

Is there a way to dynamically pass in all the props with stubs?

```
const film = true;
const ArabianNightsComponent = (Aladdin, AliBaba, ThiefOne, ThiefTwo, ..... ThiefForty) => {
    // do something with props
    const hero = film? Aladdin(): AliBaba();
    return (<div>{hero}</div>);
}
```

If I want to test this with enzye (say, using `shallow`), how do I dynamically pass in TheifOne to ThiefForty?

I've tried this:

```
let wrapper = shallow(<ArabianNights Aladdin={sinon.stub()} AliBaba={sinon.stub()}/>);
```

But I get a load of errors from PropTypes that I'm missing required props, and as well as this I get errors from lower down components, when I run `wrapper.html()` because it's missing their props.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PropTypes to figure out what props a component has, and map the values to the stubs you want to pass in.

```
let Aladdin, AliBaba;
let wrapper;
beforeEach( () => {
    Aladdin = sinon.stub();
    AliBaba = sinon.stub();
    const stubsToTest = {Aladdin, AliBaba}; // equiv. {"Aladdin": Sinon.stub() ...}
    // uses lodash to map values of oject
    const otherStubs = _.mapValues(ArabianNights.propTypes, () => sinon.stub());
    // now looks like {ThiefOne: stub, ThiefTwo: stub, ...}
    const props = {...otherStubs, ...stubToTest}; // combine objects
    wrapper = shallow(<ArabianNights {...props} />
});
```

Here, the `stubsToTest` comes after the `otherStubs` so that they aren't overwritten.

Then continue with tests as expected.